# google Apps Script - Update Log Sheet If criteria matches

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to update specific cell values from the "Payroll" sheet to the "Log" sheet based on criteria IF

Payroll sheet Emp. code in A1 and Date list starts from A3:A matches to

Log sheet Emp. code in B2:B  and  Date list starts from A2:A

then find and update the following cell (value or formula) from the Payroll sheet to the Log Sheet Date wise accordingly

Payroll to Log

F to F

B to E

C to M

D to BJ

E to BK

G to G

H to H

and prompt "data is updated!" for Emp.Name(D1:F1) and "From" K1:P1 to W1:Y1

**below code is not working - NO update is happening  - resulting "No matching row found in the Log sheet."**

[image]

[image]

[Sample working sheet link for your reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UiwpNM2S0aeo4QinbEi-NqyPkGFVoZobqareeAOCsHs/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function updateLogSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var payrollSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payroll");
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
  
  // Get the Emp.code from A1 of the Payroll sheet
  var empCode = payrollSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  
  // Get the values in the Date list from A3:A of the Payroll sheet
  var dates = payrollSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);
  
  // Find the row number in the Log sheet where the Emp.code matches B2 and the date matches one of the dates in the list
  var rowIndex = -1;
  var logValues = logSheet.getRange("A2:H").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < logValues.length; i++) {
    if (logValues[i][1] == empCode && dates.includes(logValues[i][0])) {
      rowIndex = i + 2; // Add 2 because the range starts at A2
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (rowIndex != -1) {
    // Update the cells in the Log sheet
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 5).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("B1").getValue()); // B to E
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 13).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("C1").getValue()); // C to M
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 59).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("D1").getValue()); // D to BJ
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 60).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("E1").getValue()); // E to BK
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 7).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("F1").getValue()); // F to F
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 8).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("G1").getValue()); // G to G
    logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 9).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("H1").getValue()); // H to H
    
    // Prompt the message
    var empName = payrollSheet.getRange("D1:F1").getValue();
    var message = "Data is updated for " + empName + " from " + logSheet.getRange("K1:P1").getValue() + " to " + logSheet.getRange("W1:Y1").getValue();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message);
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No matching row found in the Log sheet.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` in the code is resulting in `false` because `dates.includes(logValues[i][0])` is not resulting in `true`, I made this modification that should allow the code to continue:

```
    // The "compare" variable contains an array of length 1 
       // if the date is in "dates" or 0 if no dates are found.
    var compare = dates.filter(function (date) {
      return logValues[i][0].getTime() == date.getTime()
    });
    if (logValues[i][1] == empCode && compare.length > 0) {
      rowIndex = i + 2; // Add 2 because the range starts at A2
      break;
    }
```

---

### Update:

Use this code if you're trying to update the row that contains the matching date and Emp code from `Payroll` to `Log`:

```
function updateLogSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var payrollSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payroll");
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  // Get the Emp.code from A1 of the Payroll sheet
  var empCode = payrollSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // Get the values in the Date list from A3:A of the Payroll sheet
  var dates = payrollSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);

  // Find the row number in the Log sheet where the Emp.code matches B2 and the date matches one of the dates in the list
  var rowIndex = -1;
  var payrollIndex = -1;
  var logValues = logSheet.getRange("A2:H").getValues();
  logValues = logValues.filter(function (x) {
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || '')))
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < logValues.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
      if (dates[j].getTime() === logValues[i][0].getTime()) {
        payrollIndex = j + 3;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (logValues[i][1] == empCode && payrollIndex !== -1) {
      rowIndex = i + 2; // Add 2 because the range starts at A2
      if (rowIndex != -1) {
        // Update the cells in the Log sheet
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 5).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("B" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // B to E
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 13).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("C" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // C to M
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 59).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("D" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // D to BJ
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 60).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("E" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // E to BK
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 7).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("F" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // F to F
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 8).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("G" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // G to G
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 9).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("H" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // H to H

        payrollIndex = - 1;
        // Prompt the message

        var empName = payrollSheet.getRange("D1:F1").getValue();
        var message = "Data is updated for " + empName + " from " + logSheet.getRange("K1:P1").getValue() + " to " + logSheet.getRange("W1:Y1").getValue();
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message);
      } else {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No matching row found in the Log sheet.");
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This will only update the data in the top line of list at `Payroll`, if you want to update every single line remove the last `break;` from the code.

I was not able to fix the prompt "data is updated!" since the sample sheet doesn't have values in the ranges specified in the code, feel free to edit the file or your Question to include this data, I would update my question to take that into account.

---

### Second update:

You can use this code if you'll use logID as a unique identifier between both sheets, update the ranges under `if (rowIndex != -1) {` in order to move the values from one sheet to the other as needed:

```
function updateLogSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var payrollSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payroll");
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  // Get the Emp.code from A1 of the Payroll sheet
  var empCode = payrollSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();


  // Get the values in the Date list from A3:A of the Payroll sheet
  // var dates = payrollSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);
  var logIds = payrollSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);

  var rowIndex = -1;
  var payrollIndex = -1;

  var logValues = logSheet.getRange("A2:H").getValues();
  logValues = logValues.filter(function (x) {
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || '')))
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < logValues.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < logIds.length; j++) {
      if (logIds[j] === logValues[i][0]) {
        payrollIndex = j + 3;
      }
    }
    if (logValues[i][2] == empCode && payrollIndex !== -1) {
      rowIndex = i + 2; // Add 2 because the range starts at A2
      if (rowIndex != -1) {
        // Update the cells in the Log sheet
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 5).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("B" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // B to E
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 13).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("C" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // C to M
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 59).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("D" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // D to BJ
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 60).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("E" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // E to BK
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 7).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("F" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // F to F
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 8).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("G" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // G to G
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 9).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("H" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // H to H
        
        // Prompt the message
        var empName = payrollSheet.getRange("D1:F1").getValue();
        var message = "Data is updated for " + empName + " from " + logSheet.getRange("K1:P1").getValue() + " to " + logSheet.getRange("W1:Y1").getValue();
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message);
      } else {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No matching row found in the Log sheet.");
      }
      payrollIndex = - 1;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @HummBird I edited my answer again. You could edit your question or create a new question if you need to get code to achieve a goal that is different from the one explained in the original post.

Comment: @HummBird Create a new separate question if you now have a different problem than the one you first described in this question. Never change an existing question nor the question data/code after someone has answered with a solution to the problem your originally described.

Comment: Thank you! Your second update worked for me. faced date format-related issues. That's why I have been forced to change to code. Now LogID works. :)